# What was the red stuff Thomas was helping to dig?

Tags: plot-explanation, crimson-peak

Throughout *Crimson Peak* Thomas was helping or working with some people on a machine which digs red stuff out. What was that red stuff and what's the significance of it to the film?

Comment: Haven't watched the film yet, but everywhere says it's clay. This is also stated in the dialogue.

Comment: Did you miss the scene at the beginning where he asks Edith's father for money and explains how it's clay, which is afterall the whole (official) point of his journey to the US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What was that red stuff..

From [Wikipedia on *Crimson Peak*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Peak):

> Edith and Sir Thomas eventually marry and return to England. They arrive at Allerdale Hall, the Sharpes' dilapidated mansion, which sits atop a **red clay** mine.

The wiki page on [Red clay (disambiguation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_clay_(disambiguation)) suggests it may have been useful for pottery.

> what's the significance of it to the film?

Not sure, but note that [crimson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson) is a "strong, red color, inclining to purple". And that it has connotations of anger or embarrassment when applied to people. E.G. *"He turned crimson when his tryst with the student was revealed to the rest of the faculty"*.